# Podcast feed in Android app

Tags: android, feed, podcast

I am working on an android app for my church and would like to put our sermons on it. The company we upload our sermons to automatically makes a podcast feed for it. Basically I am looking for a way to list podcasts inside of the app. I would like it to be hardcoded to one podcast. I have looked online but cannot really find anything about. I am not sure how to code the podcast part. More than likely the actual playing can be handed off to a secondary app.

Comment: Have you found any answer to this? if so, could you share with us?

Answer (score 0):

there two steps i recommend.
A) Use the Aquery lib to parse the xml or json returned by the podcast feed link. 
Check it out https://code.google.com/p/android-query/. Doesnt matter what layout you use to display the podcast items.
B) Then you can Streaming the audio from A URL using MediaPlayer. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Good luck